# C# Adding Image to Owin Context.Response

Tags: c#, html, response, owin, middleware

my C# MVC project has authorization logic in Owin Middleware, and I want to display the error message to the browser when the user is not authrorized. My approach is to use **Response.WriteAsync()** method in the Owin Middleware to display the page. The contents of Response.WriteAsync() comes from separate "**error.html**" page, and I use File.ReadAllText() to read the contents.

I have **"error.html"** page:

```
...
<body>
     <image src = "errorImage.gif">
     <p>Not Authorized</p>
</body>
...
```

**Owin Middleware**:

```
public class middleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context){

         var errorPage = File.ReadAllText("error.html"); //Here I am reading the html page
         if(not_authorized){
              context.Response.WriteAsync(errorPage); // Displaying the page
         }

         await Next.Invoke(context);

    }

}
```

The problem of this approach is I can't display the image that associated in "error.html" page since the image is located in the server. Is there a way to display the error page with image in this case?

Answer (score 0):

pass the image as a base64 string then in the src tag reference the image from a base64 string:

```
<img src="data:[imgType ie: image/gif];base64,[base64StringYouPassedDown]" />
```